# Como mostrar certos dados dependendo de quem fez login

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma dúvida em relação ao *login* para várias pessoas.
Tenho este código:

```
<?php
    include("conectar.php");
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];

    $query = "
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM usuarios
        WHERE usuario = '" . $usuario . "' AND senha = '" . $senha . "'";
    $consulta = mysql_query($query);
    $resultado = mysql_fetch_array($consulta);

    if ($resultado[0]) {
        echo "Login realizado com sucesso!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Dados incorretos.";
    }

?>
```

Cada Login irá ter um dado especifico a mostrar de uma tabela **tb_empresa**.
Ao fazer o login, preciso mostrar os dados desse trabalhador. Sei que é necessário fazer uma query para cada utilizador. Se o login for feito por Y faz a query Y e mostra os dados Y. Se o login for feito por Z faz a query Z e mostra os dados Z. Mas não sei como fazer isso.

Estes mesmos dados encontram-se numa base de dados MySQL. Os únicos dados que podem se relacionar são os `ID_empresa` e `ID_usuario`.

Comment: A reposta resolve o seu problema? Se sim marque-a como certa.

Comment: Calma, Jorge :)

Answer (score 5):

Editei um pouco seu SQL de acordo com as informações passadas pelo comentário e ficou assim:

(Não esqueça de mudar o SQL para o seu caso, os campos coloquei ficticiosamente imaginando como estaria em sua base de dados).

> Lembrando, quando você utiliza aspas ("teste $dados teste"), você não precisa quebrar ela para adicionar uma variável ("teste" . $dados . "teste"), neste caso o PHP vai entender que existe uma variável em algum lugar e irá substituir ela.

```
$usuario = 'teste';
$senha = 'teste2123';
$querySQL = "SELECT * FROM usuarios AS usu LEFT JOIN tb_empresa AS emp ON emp\.id_usuario = usu\.id WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'";

var_dump($querySQL);
$query = mysql_query($querySQL);

if (!($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)))
{
    echo 'Usuário não encontrado!';
} else {
    echo 'Usuário encontrado!';
    var_dump($row); // Os dados estarão todos aqui, só utilizar como deseja!.
}
```

Teste e nos informe do resultado;